# Vim (python mode) Breakpoint

Tags: python, python-2.7, vim, vim-plugin, python-mode

I use Plugin 'klen/python-mode' in my vim, and work fine

but when I want add a break point and run code with `python mode`, occurs unexpected error, the vim says `[Pymode] code running ...` and vim is stops, then I must kill the process of vim

My config:

```
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1
let g:pymode_rope = 1
let g:pymode_doc_bind = "<C-S-d>"
let ropevim_enable_shortcuts = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint_bind = '<leader>k'
```

I use `python 2.7.9`

**I want use breakpoints and run code with vim but this is damaged**

Thank you very much! :D

Comment: did you figure this out? I am also not able to run it

Comment: I think that it is a bug or is not possible (You should report in the git repo ... I do not it xD), for it now I run the script out of vim... with the console, `python script.py` , please report it in https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues and then you could tell me the solution hahaha.. greetings!!

Comment: it works using !pythone %, but not with <leader>r. If you use !python3 %, maybe map it to a key, the debugger works as expected. Yeah, I do agree this is a bug. Will report it.

Answer (score 0):

Use :!python3 % instead of using the default keybinding `<leader>r`.

I am now able to put in breakpoints, and pdb works as expected. Also you can break out of an infinite loop or kill the process using Cntrl+C.